# Mysterious div being appended to hyperlinks

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

We run a Ruby on Rails 3.2 web application that uses a standard mix of rails and jquery.

Recently, we noticed a strange div element appearing in our production code. It seems to only show up when we render views with strings that also contain hyperlinks.

Here's an example:

We have a string in our view, that we want rendered as HTML:

```
"Try to search <a href='/search?q=hiring'>hiring</a>"
```

When we render the page in production though, we get the following:

```
"Try to search <a href='/search?q=hiring'>hiring</a><div style="display: none;"><a href="azarvuttcexyytzq.html" id="qqqqtra" rel="file">trufarwdstrzyzdyw</a></div>."
```

We're not sure why but the following div is being appended to our link:

```
<div style="display: none;"><a href="azarvuttcexyytzq.html" id="qqqqtra" rel="file">trufarwdstrzyzdyw</a></div>
```

What's strange is that we don't think that the file *azarvuttcexyytzq.html* exists on our servers, and we also found out that *"file"* is not an acceptable rel value for a hyperlink's relation attribute.

So, where could the div be coming from?

One thought is that it is coming from some analytics library in our system, since we're using Google Analytics. But we can't seem to confirm that idea or rule it out.

Does anyone know of a library that causes behavior like this?

Any help or insight would be appreciated.

Comment: What happens if you run the application in development? Or production, but locally? What's the HTML output of the server: before applying any Javascript to it.

Comment: We haven't reproduced it in development. I'll try to reproduce in a production environment run locally.

Comment: Did you try different browsers (w/o any browser AddOns) on different computers?

Comment: yes, we've verified it in different browsers, with addons disabled. it still happens.

Comment: It doesn't appear when we precompile our assets and run the app in production mode locally.

Comment: Another weird behavior: we can't reproduce the problem in production when we bypass the load balancers and interact directly with the web app instances.

Comment: @dandrews Did you realize where this behavior came from?

Comment: @MartinCopes yes - fortunately, it wasn't malicious at all; it was just tracking code injected by a third party proxy / cdn service that we use.

Comment: Cool, could you tell me what service is doing this?

Comment: @MartinCopes the service sniffs for ( and redirects ) malicious looking traffic

Comment: @dandrews What's the name of the service? I'm seeing the same content and I'd like to know what service is adding this

Comment: @dandrews sorry to bother you with this again but do you recall the name of the service doing this? I couldn't find anything about it in the web

Comment: @MartinCopes Distil Networks

Answer (score 0):

If there is no developer who has done this (intentionally or otherwise) by appending a `div` with a random hyperlink in your application, then there is a high probability that your application server, some library or a gem you are using is compromised. It would be good to do an audit of your code/server and ensure that you are using the original version of all the gems and libraries and no malicious code is otherwise included in your app code.

Answer (score 0):

We had the exact same issue, although intermittently, and it was Distil networks injecting in our case. To verify we took Distil out for the site and it worked like a charm! 
Although, have yet to find how to get it working with Distil, will update the answer if/when we do

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue, our application behind Distil as well as in other comments.
If you use Distil, read this: 
https://help.distilnetworks.com/hc/en-us/articles/235705127-Optimizing-Honeypot-Links-for-Pages-with-Inline-JavaScript

**In short:** Add the following comment near the top of your page (and above the JS) to force Distil injection to happen there: </a> -–> You can also add any other custom, a unique comment which Distil could use to inject the honeypot link code into.